# Shell Script Spawned From systemd Node App Doesn't Edit etc File

Tags: node.js, linux, systemd, intel-edison

I have a systemd service that starts a Node app on boot. The Node app uses `child_process.spawnSync` to launch a shell script that edits `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_cli-actions.sh` using sed.

The wpa_cli-actions.sh file is edited correctly if I launch the Node app manually from the command line, but is not edited correctly when the app is launched by systemd. My systemd service file is based on another one that launches a similar service, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I haven't seen any errors related to this in the journalctl output. Below is my service file.

```
[Unit]
Description=The Edison status and configuration service
After=mdns.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/su root -c 'node /usr/lib/config-server/app.js'
Restart=always
RestartSec=10s
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal
SyslogIdentifier=edison-config
PrivateTmp=no
Environment=NODE_ENV=production
User=root
Group=root

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Comment: is it edited at all ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try The following, And root is enabled by default if you don't specify `User` or `Group`, replace entire <**path to node>** with your path to node, it can be found with `which node`.

```
[Unit]
Description=The Edison status and configuration service
After=mdns.service

[Service]
ExecStart=<path to node> /usr/lib/config-server/app.js
WorkingDirectory=/usr/lib/config-server
Restart=always
RestartSec=10s
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal
SyslogIdentifier=edison-config
PrivateTmp=no
Environment=NODE_ENV=production


[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```